# How to get all the IDs from two XML and merge to a single XML using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to compare two responses and find out the same and different IDs from them. After that I need to merge them to a single XML document.

Here is one XML document, which is saved in some variable called $one:

```
<test>
<console>
<consoles>
<ID>123</ID>
</consoles>
<consoles>
<ID>122</ID>
</consoles>
<consoles>
<ID>134</ID>
</consoles>
</console>
</test>
```

Here is the other XML document, which is saved in some variable called $two:

```
<test>
<console>
<consoles>
<ID>123</ID>
</consoles>
<consoles>
<ID>122</ID>
</consoles>
<consoles>
<ID>134</ID>
</consoles>
<consoles>
<ID>456</ID>
</consoles>
</console>
</test>
```

What I need to do is, I need to compare both the XML documents and get the values of the IDs which are same in both the XML documents as well as the different one. So the output will look something like this:

```
<test>
<console>
<consoles>
<ID>123</ID>
</consoles>
<consoles>
<ID>122</ID>
</consoles>
<consoles>
<ID>134</ID>
</consoles>
<consoles>
<ID>456</ID>
</consoles>
</console>
</test>
```

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So basically you want the distinct values from the combined list? Which XSLT 1.0 processor will you be using? And how exactly are these variables populated?

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k I want the distinct as well as the same ID that are presented in both the XMLs. The variable will be populated after I make a call to the backend and the response will be saved in the variables. Currently, I am using XMLSpy as a processor.

Comment: I am afraid you've lost me on both counts. And AFAICT XMLSpy supports XSLT 1.0, 2.0, and 3.0 - why did you limit your question to XSLT 1.0?

Comment: XMLSpy does supports higher version of XSLT, and I am using it only for writing the XSLT. However the system where I am going to use it only supports v1.0, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, when I asked which XSLT 1.0 processor will you be using ...

Comment: It's xsltproc that supports v1.0

Comment: xsltproc supports the EXSLT [set:distinct()](http://exslt.org/set/functions/distinct/index.html) extension function - which is what I think you want.

Comment: Sorry, my requirement is to do it with XSLT only. Thanks for you help though.

Comment: Then use Muenchian grouping to get the unique values: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html:

Comment: @kjhughes Could you please share some light here.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a simple, pure XSLT 1.0 solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vRtfDoc2">
    <test>
        <console>
            <consoles>
                <ID>123</ID>
            </consoles>
            <consoles>
                <ID>122</ID>
            </consoles>
            <consoles>
                <ID>134</ID>vDoc2
            </consoles>
            <consoles>
                <ID>456</ID>
            </consoles>
        </console>
    </test>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc2" select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name = 'vRtfDoc2']/*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <test>
        <console>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/*/*"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$vDoc2/*/*[not(ID = current()/*/*/*/ID)]"/>
        </console>
    </test>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the first of the two provided XML documents:**

```
<test>
    <console>
        <consoles>
            <ID>123</ID>
        </consoles>
        <consoles>
            <ID>122</ID>
        </consoles>
        <consoles>
            <ID>134</ID>
        </consoles>
    </console>
</test>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<test>
   <console>
      <consoles>
         <ID>123</ID>
      </consoles>
      <consoles>
         <ID>122</ID>
      </consoles>
      <consoles>
         <ID>134</ID>
      </consoles>
      <consoles xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
         <ID>456</ID>
      </consoles>
   </console>
</test>
```

**Note**:

The `xsl` namespace in the result will not appear if the second document was in its own XML file and not embedded in the transformation (which here is done only for convenience).

Comment: Thanks for this Dimitre. I'll give it a try and let you know how it worked.

Comment: Hi Dimitre, I tried this but I am not able to see the difference getting printed. It is always printing whatever I have in the first XML file. http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWB9

Comment: @Sierra, in the context of that online tool, if you want to work with XSLT 1.0 and variables containing result tree fragments, to further process them, don't rely on `document('')`, instead use `exsl:node-set`, as done in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWB9/2

Comment: Thanks for your response Martin. I have a similar code here: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWR5Eb/5 but somehow is it not printing the values properly. Could you please help?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Note that there is a parallel thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58836770/how-to-compare-two-xml-responses-saved-in-a-variable-and-print-the-distinct-and?noredirect=1#comment103951525_58836770

Comment: @sierra, Please use a real XSLT 1.0 processor, such as Saxon 6, MSXML 3/4/6 or MA .NET XslCompiledTransform. Anyway, an online tool will probably not allow the `document()` function due to security concerns. For your tool, just replace `<xsl:variable name="vDoc2" select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name = 'vRtfDoc2']/*"/>` with: `<xsl:variable name="vDoc2" select="exslt:node-set($vRtfDoc2)/*"/>`